# How do I make an "infinite" UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipickerview

I have a picker view where the user is entering a time. When they scroll down to hour 23, I want hour zero to appear as the next item, and the sequence to re-start. How can I achieve this?

Here is my current picker view data source:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 3; 
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  NSArray *sectionContents = [[self dataForDatapickerRows] objectAtIndex:component];    
  NSInteger rows = [sectionContents count];     
  NSLog(@"component %d rows is: %d",component,rows);    
  return rows;  
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  self.dataPickerInstance.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];       
  return ([[[self dataForDatapickerRows ]objectAtIndex:component] objectAtIndex:row]);
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(component==0)
    {
      [self setHou:(NSInteger*)[[[self dataForDatapickerRows ]objectAtIndex:component] objectAtIndex:row]];
    }
    else if(component==1)
    {
      [self setMinut:(NSInteger*)[[[self dataForDatapickerRows ]objectAtIndex:component] objectAtIndex:row]];
    }
    else if(component==2)
    {
      [self setSecon:(NSInteger*)[[[self dataForDatapickerRows ]objectAtIndex:component] objectAtIndex:row]];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",[[[self dataForDatapickerRows ]objectAtIndex:component] objectAtIndex:row]); 
}


- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    UILabel* tView = (UILabel*)view;

    if (!tView){
        tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [tView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90,60)];
        tView.self.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        tView.minimumFontSize = 80;
        tView.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
        tView.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        tView.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
        tView.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:40];
        tView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


        //tView.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        // factLabel.frame = CGRectMake(factLabel.frame.origin.x, factLabel.frame.origin.y, factLabel.frame.size.width, lLabelSIze.height);
        //
        // Setup label properties - frame, font, colors etc
    }   // Fill the label text here
     tView.text=[[[self dataForDatapickerRows ]objectAtIndex:component] objectAtIndex:row];   

   return tView; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a custom time picker (UIPickerView), for which the delegate looks like this:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 4; // it's with am/pm in my case
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    /// 18000 is divisible with 12, 24 (for the hour) and 60 (for the minutes and seconds)
    /// it can still get to the end.. but will need a lot of scrolling
    /// I set the initial value between 9000 and 9060
    if (component==0) { // hour
        return 18000;
    }
    if (component==3) { // am/pm
        return [_datasource count];
    }
      // seconds and minutes - could use 45000 so it repeats the same number of time as the hours
    return 18000;
}
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (component==3) { // am/pm
        return [_datasource objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if (component==0) { // hour
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row%12];
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", row%60];
}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (component==3) { // am/pm
        if (row==0&&_h>11) {
            _h-=12;
        }
        if (row==1&_h<12) {
            _h+=12;
        }
    }
    else if(component==0){
        _h=row%12;
        if ([self selectedRowInComponent:3]==1) { // handle am/pm
            _h+=12;
        }
    }
    else if(component==1){
        _m=row%60;
    }
    else if(component==2){
        _s=row%60;
    }
}
-(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    // set the size for components
    if (component<3) {
        return 50;
    }
    return 70;
}
```

Comment: hi friend,   first thing  i need to say  thank to you.In your code i need to increase the row count to 18000 but i need only 24 for hour and 60 for second and minute, then what i need to do. Do u have any idea ? please share

Comment: First, remove the last component from all the methods (am/pm). Then, you'll need to modify `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` for your needs (e.g: for the hour to take values between 0-23 use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row%24]`, to take values between 1 and 24 use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row%24+1]`). The seconds and minutes already take values only between 0 and 59. Check the link from `user792677`'s post, it might explain better (it uses the same idea, and it scrolls back to the middle after a new value is selected).

Comment: oh.. you'll also need to modify `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` to return the same values (remove the first if - am/pm - at `component==0` `_h` (hour) will be row%24 (or row%24+1, depends how you use it in the `titleForRow:` method).

Comment: Hi friend, Thanks for that idea and may i know the row counts for that above logic.... is it 24,60 and 60 are greater than that... Requirement is just 24,60,60 friend within that is it possible...

Comment: let's say that the minute component is at 9832, than the minute will be 9832%60 (== 52, % being the rest for the division of 9832 to 60). Therefore the minute will be 52. if scrolling to 9833, the minute will be 53. When it scrolls to 9840, the minute will be 9840%60 (== 0), so after 59, it will show up 0 again. I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of the possible ways to do what you want, doesn't look pretty for me, but should work:
[Pauldy’s House of Geek Blog Archive The Abusive PickerView](http://www.timespace.org/2008/07/11/the-abusive-pickerview/)

You are basically creating lot, lot, lot duplicate items to simulate a loop.